# Vue ChartJS is not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuetify.js, vue-chartjs

I have a problem with the `vue-chartjs` component, which is the wrapper for `chartjs`.

The problem is that the data does not automatically redraw the chart with new incoming values.

Basically i searched the whole internet and i tried everything (`watchers`, `mixins`, `reactiveProp`, etc.)  and nothing work.

The best regards.

Here is my code.

**Package.json**

```
"@mdi/font": "^3.6.95",
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"core-js": "^3.3.2",
"eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
"roboto-fontface": "*",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
"vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3",
"vue-svg-gauge": "^1.2.1",
"vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
"vuetify": "^2.1.10",
"vuex": "^3.1.2"
```

**Chart.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <ChartLine v-if="loaded" :chartdata="chartdata" :options="options" />

          <v-card>
            <v-toolbar color="light-green" dark>
              <v-tabs v-model="tabs" background-color="transparent">
                <v-tab>A</v-tab>
                <v-tab>B</v-tab>
                <v-tab>C</v-tab>
                <v-tab>D</v-tab>
                <v-tab>E</v-tab>
              </v-tabs>
            </v-toolbar>

            <v-tabs-items v-model="tabs">
              <v-tab-item>
                <div class="small">
                  <ChartLine :chart-data="dataCollectionHour" :options="options"></ChartLine>
                </div>
              </v-tab-item>
              <v-tab-item>
                <div class="small">
                  <ChartBar :chart-data="dataCollectionDay" :options="options"></ChartBar>
                </div>
              </v-tab-item>
              <v-tab-item>
                <div class="small">
                  <ChartBar :chart-data="dataCollectionWeek" :options="options"></ChartBar>
                </div>
              </v-tab-item>
              <v-tab-item>
                <div class="small">
                  <ChartBar :chart-data="dataCollectionMounth" :options="options"></ChartBar>
                </div>
              </v-tab-item>
              <v-tab-item>
                <div class="small">
                  <ChartBar :chart-data="dataCollectionYear" :options="options"></ChartBar>
                </div>
              </v-tab-item>
            </v-tabs-items>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChartLine from "./ChartLine.vue";
import ChartBar from "./ChartBar.vue";
import config from "../config.json";

export default {
  components: {
    ChartLine,
    ChartBar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      timer: null,

      tabs: null,

      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: true
              }
            }
          ],
          xAxes: [
            {
              gridLines: {
                display: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        legend: {
          display: true
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      },

      dataCollectionHour: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Výstup",
            backgroundColor: "#EF9A9A",
            borderColor: "#D32F2F",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Síť",
            backgroundColor: "#B388FF",
            borderColor: "#4A148C",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Solární Energie",
            backgroundColor: "#FFF59D",
            borderColor: "#FBC02D",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Baterie",
            backgroundColor: "#DCEDC8",
            borderColor: "#689F38",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      dataCollectionDay: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Výstup",
            backgroundColor: "#EF9A9A",
            borderColor: "#D32F2F",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Síť",
            backgroundColor: "#B388FF",
            borderColor: "#4A148C",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Solární Energie",
            backgroundColor: "#FFF59D",
            borderColor: "#FBC02D",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Baterie",
            backgroundColor: "#DCEDC8",
            borderColor: "#689F38",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      dataCollectionWeek: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Výstup",
            backgroundColor: "#EF9A9A",
            borderColor: "#D32F2F",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Síť",
            backgroundColor: "#B388FF",
            borderColor: "#4A148C",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Solární Energie",
            backgroundColor: "#FFF59D",
            borderColor: "#FBC02D",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Baterie",
            backgroundColor: "#DCEDC8",
            borderColor: "#689F38",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      dataCollectionMounth: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Výstup",
            backgroundColor: "#EF9A9A",
            borderColor: "#D32F2F",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Síť",
            backgroundColor: "#B388FF",
            borderColor: "#4A148C",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Solární Energie",
            backgroundColor: "#FFF59D",
            borderColor: "#FBC02D",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Baterie",
            backgroundColor: "#DCEDC8",
            borderColor: "#689F38",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      dataCollectionYear: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Výstup",
            backgroundColor: "#EF9A9A",
            borderColor: "#D32F2F",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Síť",
            backgroundColor: "#B388FF",
            borderColor: "#4A148C",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Solární Energie",
            backgroundColor: "#FFF59D",
            borderColor: "#FBC02D",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Baterie",
            backgroundColor: "#DCEDC8",
            borderColor: "#689F38",
            borderWidth: 3,
            data: []
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.pollData();
  },
  methods: {
    pollData() {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.tabs === 0) {
          this.$http.get(config.chartActualPower).then(Response => {
            this.dataCollectionHour.labels = Response.body.labels;
            this.dataCollectionHour.datasets[0].data = Response.body.load;
            this.dataCollectionHour.datasets[1].data = Response.body.grid;
            this.dataCollectionHour.datasets[2].data = Response.body.pv;
            this.dataCollectionHour.datasets[3].data = Response.body.bat;
          });
        } else if (this.tabs === 1) {
          this.$http.get(config.chartDay).then(Response => {
            this.dataCollectionDay.labels = Response.body.labels;
            this.dataCollectionDay.datasets[0].data = Response.body.load;
            this.dataCollectionDay.datasets[1].data = Response.body.grid;
            this.dataCollectionDay.datasets[2].data = Response.body.pv;
            this.dataCollectionDay.datasets[3].data = Response.body.bat;
          });
        } else if (this.tabs === 2) {
          this.$http.get(config.chartWeek).then(Response => {
            this.dataCollectionWeek.labels = Response.body.labels;
            this.dataCollectionWeek.datasets[0].data = Response.body.load;
            this.dataCollectionWeek.datasets[1].data = Response.body.grid;
            this.dataCollectionWeek.datasets[2].data = Response.body.pv;
            this.dataCollectionWeek.datasets[3].data = Response.body.bat;
          });
        } else if (this.tabs === 3) {
          this.$http.get(config.chartMounth).then(Response => {
            this.dataCollectionMounth.labels = Response.body.labels;
            this.dataCollectionMounth.datasets[0].data = Response.body.load;
            this.dataCollectionMounth.datasets[1].data = Response.body.grid;
            this.dataCollectionMounth.datasets[2].data = Response.body.pv;
            this.dataCollectionMounth.datasets[3].data = Response.body.bat;
          });
        } else if (this.tabs === 4) {
          this.$http.get(config.chartYear).then(Response => {
            this.dataCollectionYear.labels = Response.body.labels;
            this.dataCollectionYear.datasets[0].data = Response.body.load;
            this.dataCollectionYear.datasets[1].data = Response.body.grid;
            this.dataCollectionYear.datasets[2].data = Response.body.pv;
            this.dataCollectionYear.datasets[3].data = Response.body.bat;
          });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.small {
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.v-card {
  height: 650px;
}
</style>
```

**ChartLine.vue**

```
<script>
import VueCharts from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: VueCharts.Line,
  mixins: [VueCharts.mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: ["options"],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
};
</script>
```

**ChartBar.vue**

```
<script>
import VueCharts from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: VueCharts.Bar,
  mixins: [VueCharts.mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: ["options"],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the **options** prop only and not the **chartdata** prop:

```
  props: ["options"],
```

but you use both of them

```
this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
```

See [Example](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-props)

Also please pay attention to all the mentioned caveats in the section "Updating charts" of the guide.

Comment: According to https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts *reactiveProp* -> It extends the logic of your chart component and automatically creates a prop named chartData and adds a vue watch on this prop. I already tried that solution with both props and it has no effect.

Comment: Can you create a live problem example on jsfiddle, for instance, please?